# Change the text box value onchange of select in system.xml of custom magento extension

Tags: module, magento-1, magento-enterprise, system.xml

I have added select option `SFTP host` with values `production, sandbox` in my system.xml file of custom extenstion. There is one text field `SFTP port` in system.xml. I want to set the text field value on change of selection.

If I select production , then port value = 22
If I select sandbox ,  then port value  = 21

```
<ftphost translate="label">
<label>SFTP host</label>
<frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
<source_model>gb/system_config_source_sftp</source_model>
<sort_order>60</sort_order>
<show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
<show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
<show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</ftphost>
<ftpport translate="label">
 <label>SFTP port</label>
 <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
 <sort_order>70</sort_order>
 <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
 <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
 <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
 </ftpport>
```

new system.xml

```
<liveenvironment translate="label">
                            <label>Live environment</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                             <comment><model>gb_gbgsp/system_config_source_sftpcomment</model>
     </comment>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </liveenvironment>
```

comment.php

```
<?php 
class gb_gbgsp_Model_Adminhtml_System_Config_Source_Sftpcomment extends Mage_Core_Model_Config_Data
{
    public function getCommentText(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element $element, $currentValue)
    {

    $result = "<script type='text/javascript'>    

            function init_comment()
            {

                $('#carriers_gbgsp_liveenvironment').observe('change', function(){
                    var field_value = $('#carriers_gbgsp_liveenvironment').getValue();
                    alert(field_value);
                });
            }
            document.observe('dom:loaded', function(){init_comment();});
            </script>";

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<liveenvironment translate="label">
                            <label>Live environment</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
    <comment><![CDATA[
                             <script type='text/javascript'>    

            function init_comment()
            {

                $('carriers_gbgsp_liveenvironment').observe('change', function(){
                    var field_value = $('carriers_gbgsp_liveenvironment').getValue();
                    alert(field_value);
                });
            }
            document.observe('dom:loaded', function(){init_comment();});
            </script>
                             ]]>  </comment>
    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </liveenvironment>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add your js through comment model

```
<ftphost translate="label">
    <label>SFTP host</label>
    <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
    <source_model>gb/system_config_source_sftp</source_model>
    <comment> <![CDATA[<script type='text/javascript'>    

        function init_comment()
        {

            $('yourslelectid').observe('change', function(){
                var field_value = $('yourslelectid').getValue();
                //add your condition here
            });
        }
        document.observe('dom:loaded', function(){init_comment();});
        </script>]]
     </comment>
    <sort_order>60</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
    </ftphost>
```

Comment: I tried this but nothing happen

Comment: did you add your field #ids in this function?

Comment: Yup. I have created class comment.php in my model folder and integrated my selectbox id in it.

Comment: did it try alert in function it is working or not?

Comment: I tried it but no luck. I believes it doesn't get called

Comment: ad your commnet.php too and latest system.xml

Comment: $('#carriers_gbgsp_liveenvironment') remove # this is prototype not jquery and some text with script so you can see this is called or not

Comment: I have added latest code in question -  new system.xml

Comment: did you changes the from $('#carriers_gbgsp_liveenvironment') to $('carriers_gbgsp_liveenvironment')

Comment: Done. I have added my javascript code in  <comment><![CDATA[]] </comment> of system.xml 

Thanks you so much for giving me hint.

Comment: i totally forgot about direct method